# Very weak wifi signal on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS running Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)

Tags: wireless

The wifi signal is not full even if I am sitting next to the router.

$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

The above command results the following :

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:098a]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e09a]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
```

Please help. Thank you.

Thanks Sir @jeremy31, Here is the output of modinfo ath10k_pci

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-30-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-3.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware.bin
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Atheros QCA988X PCIe devices
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
version:        backported from Linux (next-20151120-0-ga78de01) using backports backports-20151120-0-g906a6b3
srcversion:     EBB3D4E36DE49B7EC8057D0
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000042sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000040sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000003Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000041sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000003Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        ath10k_core,compat
vermagic:       4.2.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           irq_mode:0: auto, 1: legacy, 2: msi (default: 0) (uint)
parm:           reset_mode:0: auto, 1: warm only (default: 0) (uint)
```

Comment: Please edit to add `modinfo ath10k_pci` thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try a newer backports first

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.4.2/backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
cd backports-20151120
sudo make uninstall
```

Reboot

```
cd backports-4.4.2-1
make defconfig-ath10k
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and see if it is any better, if it isn't I would want to look at the wireless card to see if the antenna(s) are still attached

After a kernel update you will need to

```
cd backports-4.4.2-1
make clean
make defconfig-ath10k
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot

Comment: Thanks Sir @Jeremy31, with newer backports installed the problem is solved. The network is more stable now. Thanks again .

Comment: My goodness, I think I again messed up something after I ran 'sudo apt-get autoclean/autoremove' . Sir @Jeremy31 can you please let me know how can I reinstall the newer backports drivers.

Comment: What is `uname -a`